# RuntimeError: Failed to initialize PocketSphinx

Tags: python, runtime, speech-recognition, pocketsphinx

I am making a Jarvis and for some reason I'm getting an error, when I say something. The error message is shown below:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1 (threaded_listen):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 754, in threaded_listen 
    if running[0]: callback(self, audio)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\pr\AI\SMITH\main.py", line 24, in callBack
    speech_as_text = recognizer.recognize_sphinx(audio, keyword_entries=keywords)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 817, in recognize_sphinx
    decoder = pocketsphinx.Decoder(config)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "_pocketsphinx.pyx", line 852, in _pocketsphinx.Decoder.__init__
RuntimeError: Failed to initialize PocketSphinx
```

It should wait for the keyword *hey smith*, and then execute the command.
But if I say anything, I just get that strange error message.
Here is the code I wrote:

```py
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import time
from openpyxl import *
import random
import pocketsphinx


r = sr.Recognizer()
keywords = [('smith',1), ('smith',1)]
src = sr.Microphone()

def Speech(txt):
  rate = 100
  engine = pyttsx3.init()
  voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
  engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)
  engine.setProperty('rate', rate+85)
  engine.say(txt)
  engine.runAndWait()
  
def callBack(recognizer, audio):
  try:
    speech_as_text = recognizer.recognize_sphinx(audio, keyword_entries=keywords)
    print(speech_as_text)
    if 'smith' or 'smit' in speech_as_text:
      Speech('Yes?')
      recMain()
  except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Repeat please!")
  
def startRec():
  print("...")
  r.listen_in_background(src, callBack)
  time.sleep(1000000)
  
def recMain():
  r = sr.Recognizer()
  with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say")
    audio = r.listen(source)
    data = ""
  try:
    data = r.recognize_sphinx
    data.lower()
    print("The ask was: ", data)
    
    if "hello" in data:
      Speech('Hi!')
      
    else:
      Speech("Sorry, i didn't get it!")
      
  except sr.UnknownValueError:
      print('I did not understand it.')
  
  except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Well, I'm gonna crash {0}".format(e))
    
def excel():
  wb = load_workbook("cmds.xlsx")
  wu = wb.get_sheet_by_name('User')
  wr = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Replies')
  
  global helloList
  
  urow = wu['1']
  helloList = [urow[x].value for x in range(len(urow))]
  
  global reply_helloList
  rrow = wr['1']
  
  reply_helloList = [rrow[x].value for x in range(len(rrow))]

while 1:
  startRec()
```